# How can I prove that $b^n$ is $ O(n!)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi guys I came upon an exercise from the Big-O chapter that I can not solve.I know that in order to be in $O\bigl(f(n)\bigr)$ has to be smaller or equal to $c$ * $f(n)$ where is c is a constant and is positive but I never solved an exercise where another constant, $b$ in my case, is involved ($b$ is greater than 1 and is real). Any help is highly appreciated, sorry for the writing issues..

Comment: Hint: show that if $b \geq 2$ is an integer, and $n \geq 1$ is an integer, $b^n \leq b^b n!$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use *Stirling's formula* to prove that yoou have a stronger statement::
$$b^n=o(n!)$$

Answer (score 0):

For $b>1$, $m=\lfloor  b  \rfloor$ and enough big $n$
$$ \frac{b^n}{n!} = \underbrace{\frac{b}{1}\cdot \frac{b}{2} \cdots \frac{b}{m}}_{\lfloor b \rfloor}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{b}{m+1}\cdot \frac{b}{m+2} \cdots \frac{b}{n}}_{n-\lfloor  b  \rfloor}<\frac{b^m}{m!} \cdot \left(\frac{b}{m+1} \right)^{n-m} \to 0$$